# Illegal instruction in std::string

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code:

```
class USerializer {
public:
    template<typename T>
    static std::string serialize(std::list<T*> listOfObjectToSerialize)
    {
        // stringstream containing serialized Objects
        std::stringstream serializedObjectList;

        typename std::list<T*>::iterator iter;

        // serialize Objects
        for (iter = listOfObjectToSerialize.begin(); iter != listOfObjectToSerialize.end(); ++iter)
        {
            // Class delimiter
            serializedObjectList << '+'<< endl;

            // Need to serialise the class itself, and not the pointer to it!
            serializedObjectList << **iter;
        }

        return serializedObjectList.str();
    }
}
```

and then I use this methods like this:

```
std::string serializedAlarmInfo = USerializer::serialize<CcAlarm::AlarmInfo>(getActiveAlarms());
```

I am getting a SIGILL fault:

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
```

Using gdb I traced the execution and everything seems fine until I exit the serialize function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code, and see exactlty when seg fault occurs.

Comment: Please see above I updated my question

Comment: @KCH: clearly, **no** seg fault occurs! `SIGILL` is an entirely different signal, indicating that something is being executed which isn't program code, e.g., an attempt to call a virtual function on a non-existing object.

Comment: mm I see, but again I don't get it, using gdb I was able to step through everyline of serialize and as soon as I returned back to where I call the function from I got this SIGILL

Comment: @Dietmar - you are right, but I just wanted to suggest using a debugger.

Comment: could it be that "return serializedObjectList.str()" is not a good thing, since as soon as I exit serialize(..) the string is distroyed?

Comment: Although I don't see where in your code, I'd suspect that your stack got corrupted and when the calling function is being restored it reads the wrong pointer. The stack corruption would happen some time before the signal is issued. You might want to run your code with valgrind or purify to see where it accesses the wrong memory.

Comment: @Kam - I don't think so, because stringstream::str() returns string by value, not by reference or pointer.

Comment: Just as a side note: [don't use std::endl](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/). Especially for string streams it just causes an entirely unnecessary call which has no effect other than costing some time. Also, you are really using an `std::ostringstream` (not the extra `o`).

Comment: Also, don't use normal collections (`list`, `vector`, `map`) of normal pointers. Either use collections specifically designed to hold pointers or use collections of smart pointers. (Sometimes an exception is reasonable if the collection does not own the objects it holds pointers to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if ((*iter) == NULL)
{    throw std::runtime_error("Was not expecting that");
}
// Or use some other technique to compensate for a NULL pointer.
serializedObjectList << **iter;
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if this would fix and/or detect the problem because a null pointer reference would, indeed, be a seg fault but signal reported is a `SIGILL`!

Comment: Given the code above. That's the error. There is potentialy other errors in the code we can not see. But since I can't see them I can't diagnose them. **BUT** I can easily see the above generating and SIGILL.

Comment: If a null pointer dereference causes a `SIGILL` the system is broken. A null pointer dereference causes a `SIGSEGV`. The rules under which what kind of signal is generated aren't arbitrary. The problem may be a stray pointer but I would be **very** surprised if it is a null pointer!

Comment: Who said anything about de-referencing. De-referencing a NULL pointer can do anything (it does not guarantee any behavior so assuming you will get a SIGSEGV is just bad reasoning). Stop making assumptions and test it.

Comment: According to the C++ standard dereferencing a pointer can, indeed to anything. However, there are other relevant standards, e.g., POSIX, which give definitions on what is to happen in certain cases. Wikipedia [list the POSIX signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV#SIGSEGV) and `SIGILL` is rather unlikely to result from use of a null pointer. Another reason making a null pointer an unlikely cause of the problem is that the problem occurs when the function returns which is typically an indication of a corrupted stack.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Your argument is flawed. Anything can happen when the pointer is NULL. A stack corruption is the most likely reason for a SIGILL (causing any number of problems). Doing something with a NULL pointer is just as just as likely to do that as generate a SIGSEGV. The above is the only error in the provided code. So lets fix it and see what happens. Stop arguing hypothetical that you can only guess at and actually try it.

Comment: Dietmar's presumption that a NULL pointer will cause SIGSEGV and not SIGILL is based on the fact that on most modern systems (and all modern desktop/server systems) with MMUs, page zero (and perhaps a few additional pages following it) are marked neither readable, writable, nor executable for user-mode code.  It is this attribute that allows the OS to trap NULL pointer dereferences (which incidentally occur in the same fashion if you dereference address 0x00000001, 0x00000002, or any other address in page zero).  I.e, if you try to read, write, or execute anything in that page, bam! SIGSEGV.

Comment: On such systems, an instruction fetch attempt in those protected pages won't even succeed to the point that you could even get an illegal instruction exception/interrupt (a hardware term), which is the trigger for a SIGILL.  So from that standpoint, no, not "anything" can happen when a pointer is NULL.  Though its behavior is undefined by the C++ standard, its behavior is defined by most platforms.  The only exception is if, in dereferencing it, the offset of the dereference falls outside the bounds of the protected MMU page(s).

Comment: @phonetagger: Making assumptions. I find it best to make none. The C++ standard says UB. That's all the counts. Anything else is irrelevant as we don't have enough information in the question to make any further assumptions. You are merely speculating about machines you are familiar without without relating that to the context of the question (as there is no context) and thus your speculations are just that speculations). All we know is that it is UB from this dragon farts are allowed.

Comment: If the OP tests and finds that this is not the primary problem. Fine. But using this will solve another problem he has. But at least we will have ruled this out. don't speculate test.

Comment: I will be testing this solution in few hours :) I really appreciate your help with this

Comment: @Loki you were right :) the list that I receive contains mostly non NULL pointers but the last object turned out to be NULL and adding the protection fixed the issue. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl: Its interesting what happens when you don't make assumptions :-)

Comment: @phonetagger: Its interesting what happens when you don't make assumptions :-)

Comment: @LokiAstari: Well, I *am* surprised! You win!

Comment: Yes I am running in Kernel Mode, on a POSIX system where kernel has been customized for my company's needs (sorry don't have more info about that)